# Regex: Get penultimate part of a "path"

Tags: regex, oracle

I've got something like this:

```
>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD
```

With

```
([^>]*$)
```

I get the last part `DDD` . How can I get the part before it, `CCC`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR('>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD', '([^>]+)>[^>]+$', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

The `([^>]+)>[^>]+$` regex will match and capture into Group 1 any 1+ chars other than `>`, then will match `>` followed with any 1+ chars other than `>` up to the end of the string.

The last argument, `1`, tells `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to return just the captured substring.

See [**online demo**](https://rextester.com/GWXJI36590).

Another approach is to replace the whole string but keep the captured part of your choice:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE( '>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD', '.*>([^>]+)>[^>]+$', '\1')
```

See another [online demo](https://rextester.com/TCBPP20956).

Here, `.*>` will match all the string up to the `>`, then `([^>]+)` will capture any 1+ chars other than `>` and then `>[^>]+$` will match and consume `>` and 1+ chars other than `>` at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks! But that's not working with my oracle version, Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0. Too many arguments. I can use the CCC>DDD output into another regex to get this time the first chunk. Not too classy tho.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla I added a replacing approach. Also, is the number of `>`-separated chunks fixed?

Comment: no, its variable. That's why I count starting from the end, because the only sure thing is that i need the last and penultimate chucks.

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla Good, so the second solution with `REGEXP_REPLACE` works, right?

Comment: Yes, just tested. Thanks a lot regex master! :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regular expressions for this - standard string functions suffice, and they will be much faster.

In the last example, notice that there is no "second-to-last" or penultimate part; so the output is NULL. That is indeed the correct answer in that case.

```
with
  test_data (pth) as (
    select '>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD' from dual union all
    select null               from dual union all
    select '>EEE>GGG'         from dual union all
    select '>JJJJJ'           from dual
  )
select pth,
       substr(pth, instr(pth, '>', -1, 2) + 1, 
              instr(pth, '>', -1, 1) - instr(pth, '>', -1, 2) - 1) as stl
from   test_data
;

PTH               STL             
----------------  ----------------
>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD  CCC             

>EEE>GGG          EEE             
>JJJJJ
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a silly workaround for the lack of support for returning subexpressions in your version of Oracle. I offer this just as a curiosity; I proposed a better solution that doesn't use regular expressions at all in a separate Answer.

```
with
  test_data (pth) as (
    select '>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD' from dual union all
    select null               from dual union all
    select '>EEE>GGG'         from dual union all
    select '>JJJJJ'           from dual
  )
select pth, 
       regexp_substr(pth, '[^>]*', 1, nullif(2*regexp_count(pth, '>')-2, 0)) as stl
from   test_data
;

PTH              STL             
---------------- ----------------
>AAA>BBB>CCC>DDD CCC             

>EEE>GGG         EEE             
>JJJJJ
```